# All combinations of a list of objects. All objects down to a lone one

Tags: c#, combinations

I have searched and found very many algorithms in this topic but have not found one that fits this. I have also not found anyone I managed to change so my problem is resolved.

I need a function that takes a List and then returns a List with a List of all these combinations. The lists should be combinations with all objects down to only one lone object.

Example:

```
fun(new List<obj> {objA, objB, objC});
```

Should return

```
public List<List<obj>> fun(List<obj> L){

...

return List{
            List{objA},
            List{objB},
            List{objC},
            List{objA, objB},
            List{objA, objC},
            List{objB, objC},
            List{objA, objB, objC};
}
```

And I do not know in advance how long the list will be.

I know the mathematical expression

n! / k! (n-k)! + n! / (k-1)! (n-(k-1))! + ... + n! / 1! (n-1)!

Where n is the number of available objects and k is the number of them you want to combine.
The result of this calculation will be the number of List< obj > that will be included in the returned List

But, as I said, I have not managed to get something sensible in code.

I use c# so I prefer answers in this language. But all help is welcome.

I have looked at so many algorithms that I now get more confused than it helps.

Comment: What have you tried so far?, have you got any example input \ testable code that we can work with as at the moment the question is a little broad and will get you a lot of opinions and different answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an integral value to count up through all the combinations.

Then, for each value, check each bit in the number. Each `1` bit means that the corresponding item is included in the combination.

If you think about how binary numbers work, you'll understand how this algorithm works. For example, for 3 items, you will have a 3-bit binary number that goes from 001 to 111 with each of the 3 bits corresponding to one of the items, like so:

```
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

You should be able to see how we can use each bit to decide whether or not the corresponding item is included in that combination.

Here's a sample implementation - this works if the number of items is <= 32:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(IList<T> items)
{
    return Combinations(items.Count).Select(comb => comb.Select(index => items[index]));
}

public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> Combinations(int n)
{
    long m = 1 << n;

    for (long i = 1; i < m; ++i)
        yield return bitIndices((uint)i);
}

static IEnumerable<int> bitIndices(uint n)
{
    uint mask = 1;

    for (int bit = 0; bit < 32; ++bit, mask <<= 1)
        if ((n & mask) != 0)
            yield return bit;
}
```

You can test this with, for example, a list of characters A..E:

```
IList<char> test = "ABCDE".ToList();

foreach (var comb in Combinations(test))
    Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(comb));
```

This outputs:

```
A
B
AB
C
AC
BC
ABC
D
AD
BD
ABD
CD
ACD
BCD
ABCD
E
AE
BE
ABE
CE
ACE
BCE
ABCE
DE
ADE
BDE
ABDE
CDE
ACDE
BCDE
ABCDE
```

If you want to turn the `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` into a `List<List<T>>`, just do the following:

```
List<List<T>> list = Combinations(inputList).Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();
```

For example, for the `List<char>` above do this:

```
List<List<char>> list = Combinations(test).Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about performance, but from a readability point of view this is the best I came up with - using a couple of nested loops and linq's Skip and Take:

```
var source = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
var target = new List<List<int>>();


for(var i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
{
    for(var j = i; j < source.Count; j++)
    {
        target.Add(new List<int>(source.Skip(i).Take(source.Count - j)));
    }
}
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/MEUM79275)

Comment: Good try. However, if you increase elements in the source list, there will be missing combinations. 

For example, source {1, 2, 3, 4} results look like this: 

{1} , 
{1, 2}, 
{1, 2, 3}, 
{1, 2, 3, 4}, 
{2}, 
{2, 3}, 
{2, 3, 4}, 
{3} ,
{3, 4} ,
{4}. 

And then missing {1, 3} and {1, 4}. 
If there is a solution to this, then it's just such an algorithm I'm looking for.

Comment: Good catch. I don't have the time to rewrite it now but perhaps tomorrow.